# Toggling items with JQuery hides upper level lists

Tags: jquery, html

I have nested lists where I want to click and expand the underlying list. While clicking on a first level list item works fine, on the second level, clicking opens a new level but hides itself. Here is a simple example :

```
<ul>
<li> 1   
    <ul>
    <li> 1.1 </li>
    <li> 1.2 
      <ul>
        <li>
          1.2.1
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li> 2 
    <ul>
    <li> 2.1 </li>
    <li> 2.2 </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

And here is the JQuery I use:

```
$(function () {
    $('li').click(function () {
        $(this).children('ul').toggle(); //Tried next('ul') too which does not work
    });
});
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sdbU3/1/)

I would like to click and see only next level children, and clicking on a child that might have children would open the underlying list, or do nothing in the other case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/). This prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any **parent handlers** from being notified of the event.

```
$('li').click(function() {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find('ul').eq(0).toggle();
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/sdbU3/228/)

Comment: Very nice! Thanks a lot sir!

Comment: In your fiddle, click on "1" it's toggling and click on "2" it's not toggling.

Comment: @PhaniKumarM that's because the fiddle provided by OP had a problem. It had `ul` as a sibling of `li`. Check the updated fiddle in the answer

Comment: @PhaniKumarM Oups my bad